# Increment a value in a nested object?

Tags: mongodb

I am messing around with mongodb and node.js this weekend and I'm having some trouble getting through the mongodb docs regarding updating nested objects/documents.

I have a collection in which the documents look like this..

```
{
 gameName: "string",
 slug: "string",
 players: [{playerName, playerScore}, ...]
}
```

I'm trying to find out how to increment the value of playerScore based on the playerName.

I suppose this mostly comes down to me not understanding NoSQL method. I even have second thoughts about using an array for the players, so any input would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The structure you want is:

```
{
 gameName: "string",
 slug: "string",
 players: [ { playerName: "string", playerScore: number} ] , ...]
}
```

To increment player score by one if his name is Joe you would use:

```
db.collection.update( {"players.playerName":"Joe"}, { $inc : { "players.$.playerScore" : 1 } }
```

Comment: I'm confused by the poster's structure. What does {playerName, playerScore} mean?

Comment: I see the confusion - I was assuming that players was an array of documents where each document contained { playerName: "string", playerScore: "number"} but of course that's not what he wrote.  We'll have to wait till he comes back and clarifies, I guess...

Comment: Yes - sorry, I thought the structure was implicit enough to skip specifying a data type for the nested object. I was able to get what you specified to work with a single game, however it didn't seem to work as well if I try to look up a specific game. I've put this on the back burner for now while I get some real work done thought :)

Comment: For multiple games you want to add another query specifier like this: {"gameName: "string1", "players.playerName":"Joe"}

Answer (score 5):

I believe that you would have to structure your document instead like

```
{
 gameName: "string",
 slug: "string",
 players: {playerName: {score: playerScore}},
}
```

Then you can update the score with:

```
db.games.update({"gameName": "string"},
                {$inc: {"players.playerName.score": 1}
                })
```

Comment: how will this document handle multiple players?  What was wrong with original question's document structure?  Seems he wants to represent multiple players in a game.   Are you proposing one document per player, per game?  How will you know to update the correct one, there is no selector other than gameName in your update...

Comment: playerName is just a placeholder here. It could be {$inc: {"players.bobby.score": 1}}

Comment: this does not look like valid document unless you really plan to have different field _name_ to represent each player.  As a clarification, how would you get a list of player names for a particular game from this document structure?

Comment: players is an embedded document where the keys are the player names, and the values are the attributes about the player. to get a list of players in a game, fetch the "players" sub-document for the game and iterate over the keys.

Comment: poor answer because you need to accommodate dynamic number of players